# Nunit testing using FirstOrDefaultAsync()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, async-await

I have the following method:

```
public async Task<string> GetDescription(int codeId)
    {
        var Codes = Context.Codes.Where(x => x.Id == codeId).FirstOrDefault();
        return Codes.Description;
    }
```

and the following unit test:

```
[Test]
public async Task GetDescription()
{
    var result = await _serivce.GetSpecialtyDescription(1);
    Assert.That(result == "description");
}
```

and I setup my test like this:

```
public ServicesTests()
        {
            _dbContext = new Mock<LocalContext>();

            var CodeList = new List<Codes>() { new Codes() { Id = 1, Description = "description" } };
            var dbSetCodeList = MockDbSet.GetQueryableMockDbSet(CodeList);
            _dbContext.Setup(x => x.Codes).Returns(dbSetCodeList.Object);

            _context = new DataContext<LocalContext, LocalContext>(_dbContext.Object);
            _serivce = new CodesServices(_context);
        }

public static Mock<DbSet<T>> GetQueryableMockDbSet<T>(List<T> sourceList) where T : class
        {
            var queryable = sourceList.AsQueryable();

            var dbSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
            dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);
            dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
            dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
            dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => queryable.GetEnumerator());
            dbSet.Setup(d => d.Add(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>((s) => sourceList.Add(s));

            return dbSet;
        }
```

Which all works fine.

Now, I want to await the function, so do this:

```
public async Task<string> GetDescription(int codeId)
    {
        var Codes = await Context.Codes.Where(x => x.Id == codeId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        return Codes.Description;
    }
```

but this breaks my unit test - even though the code still works.

I have read plenty of articles and posts explaining that this does not work as the async methods cannot be mocked (I think?), but I have not come across anything which shows me how to resolve this.

I would be disappointing if I was forced to choose between awaiting my code or having a unit test, and feel sure there must be a way around this?

Comment: "breaks your test" how exactly?  What actually fails?

Comment: The test fails because nothing gets returned on the line that calls firstordefault()

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that code per-se (in `GetDescription()` anyway), and NUnit (more recent versions anyway) supports async tests with no issue.  If you're getting no data back, the code you're calling is returning no data.

Comment: @sellotape can you advise what version of NUnit supports this. I am currently using 3.6 which seems to be the latest version according to Nuget, but it does not support this async method

Comment: NUnit has supported it for [quite some time](http://simoneb.github.io/blog/2013/01/19/async-support-in-nunit/); that version definitely supports it.

Comment: @sellotape that post you references allows you to await the testing method, but not to test code that contains firstordefaultAsync in the actual code. Please see the question above/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not happy with the result, but this is the best I can do so far:

```
public async Task<string> GetDescription(int codeId)
    {
        var Codes = await GetAll();
        return Codes.Description;
    }

        private async Task<DbSet<Codes>> GetAll()
        {
            return Context.Codes;
        }
```

If anyone has a better suggestion please let me know.

Comment: That won't compile as GetAll() (effectively) returns a collection.

Comment: @sellotape it does compile and returns the expected value

Comment: Are you 100% sure?  You have the method marked as `async` but don't use `await` in it, so the compiler should at least complain about that (but can allow it).  `Context.Codes` is of type `DbSet<Codes>`, but the method return type is actually `**Task**<DbSet<Codes>`, so that shouldn't work either.  Even if it somehow gets past that you're returning `DbSet<>`, which doesn't have a `Description` property; only a single item selected from it (of type `Codes`) has that property.  I don't see how it could compile.

Comment: @sellotape you should give it a go - you do get a warning saying the method doe snot contain the await function, but it does compile, run and return the expected result. As far as I am aware the await function is not compulsory.

Comment: It seems the `async` modifier is causing the compiler to auto-convert the `DbSet<Codes>` to `Task<DbSet<Codes>>` - that part makes sense now, although I've not seen it before as I set all warnings as errors, so the modifier without any`await`s would always have flagged as an error.  However... `Codes.Description` on mine does not compile at all.  What EF version are you using?

Comment: @sellotape I agree - adding await will remove the Task  from the returned DbSet

Comment: Well I still can't see how `DbSet<Codes>.Description` will work, so if it compiles perhaps you have an extension method somewhere.  I think to help you further you'll need to post some [minimal code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can compile and run ourselves; then we can see what is happening.